# React Router <Link /> not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can get my components and their child components to load just fine, but I am having issues with the `<Link/>` component. I am trying to use it within my main app component that looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var Navigation = require('./navigation');
var UserActions = require('../actions/userActions.js');
var UserStore = require('../stores/userStore.js');

var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { currentUser: "" }
    },

    componentWillMount: function(){
      var user = UserStore.getUser();
      this.setState({currentUser: user })
    },

    render: function(){
       return (
            <div>
                <div id="nav-container">
                  <Navigation user={this.state.currentUser}/> 
                </div>
                <div id="main-content"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Here is the relevant part of my navigation component. I can manually navigate to the URL and everything works.

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var Link = require('react-router').Link;


var Navigation = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      return (
      {(this.isAdmin())?
          <div className="nav-parent">
              <p onClick={this.showChildren}>ADMIN TOOLS</p>
                 <ul className="child-nav">
                     <li><Link to={'admin/logos'}>Logos</Link></li>
                  </ul>
           </div>
         :null}
        )
   }
})
```

Here are the routes

```
     <Route path="/admin" component={require('./components/admin/admin.js')}>
         <Route path="logos" component={require('./components/admin/logos.js')}></Route>
  </Route>
```

I am getting the following error in the console when clicking on the react generated link:

```
bundle.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Navigation manually to the url works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your Route declaration to:

```
<Route path="/admin" component={require('./components/admin/admin.js')}>
    <Route path="logos" component={require('./components/admin/logos.js')} />
</Route>
```

And your link to:

```
<li><Link to={'/admin/logos'}>Logos</Link></li>
```

If that don't work, click in the more details arrow in your error at Console and check where it's happening.

Comment: Didn't fix my problem unfortunately. The detailed errors aren't much help either

Comment: Could you share the exception stack trace like you can see here - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#viewing-exception-stack-trace - this way you can find the real function where the error is coming from.